# Find all inputs with special attribute name, where part of name is javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("td[id^='td0_']")
```

My question is how can I replace `0` in the example above with a variable `myvar`?

Comment: jQuery selectors are just strings.  Just concat the `myvar` variable to the string.

Comment: OK, no problems, I'll just delete it. Sorry, my fault, I've tried ' instead of " and was surprised it doesn't work. not very careful. Thanks for downvoting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
$("td[id^='td" + myvar + "_']")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the quotes appropriately.

```
$("td[id^='td" + myvar +"_']")
```